# Promise not being executed using chained promises node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

i've got a problem with this code using node.js

Apparently the following promise is not being executed:

```
return bloguers.replaceOne({id: bloguer.id}, bloguer,{upsert:true}, function (err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(400).end();
                    });
```

Here's the rest of the function:

```
.post(function (req,res){
                var bloguers = db.collection('bloguers');
                var bloguer = req.body;
                console.log(bloguer.id);
                bloguers.findOne({id: bloguer.id}).then( function (respon){
                    if(respon != null){
                        console.log('dentro if');
                        return bloguers.replaceOne({id: bloguer.id}, bloguer,{upsert:true}, function (err){
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(400).end();
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        return bloguers.insertOne(bloguer).then(function (r){

                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.status(400).end();
                        });
                    }
                }).then(function(r){
                    res.json(r);
                })
            });
```

as you can see the console.log('dentro if') is executed, but the promise is not.

Answer (score 0):

If `replaceOne` does indeed return a promise then you probably shouldn't be passing a callback to it.

Change this:

```
return bloguers.replaceOne({id: bloguer.id}, bloguer,{upsert:true}, function (err){
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400).end();
});
```

To this:

```
return bloguers.replaceOne({id: bloguer.id}, bloguer,{upsert:true})
  .then(function () {
    res.status(400).end();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I'm not familiar with the API you're using (native MongoDB driver?) but if the API already supports promises then it likely doesn't return a promise if it detects that you passed it a callback.

Comment: Indeed i'm using MongoDB driver and it does return a promise. however i tried your code but still the promise is note being executed(tried putting a console log inside the .then().